# Why has the behavior of `input type="date"` changed?

Tags: html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Date inputs such as `<input type="date" name="due_date" id="due_date" min="2011-09-01" maxlength="10" class="span8">` in Chrome used to allow the user to see a "pop-up" calendar to help choose a date. I noticed yesterday that behavior has stopped; the input only allows the user to arrow up/down the date parts (month/day/year). I visited the Chrome blog and ran a Google search, but can't find any mention of this change. **Why has the behavior of `input type="date"` changed?** Curiously, this change seems to be limited to Bootstrap, as http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date still exhibits the datepicker.

Comment: Have created a JSFiddle using the Bootstrap CSS and doesn't seem to affect Chrome's popup - http://jsfiddle.net/BxVDx/3/

Comment: I just confirmed this is a Bootstrap issue by going to Bootstrap's documentation and "inserting" `<label for="date1">Choose date</label><input type="date" name="date1" id="date1">` into the default form example at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms.

Comment: @PirateKitten: I *do* see this problem in your fiddle. I'm using Chrome....Version 25.0.1364.97 m. You?

Comment: Yep just confirmed that my Chrome was slightly out of date, have updated and now seeing as you describe, so Chrome behaviour has changed as you thought. Sorry, I lost what version I was on so I can't quote it.

Comment: @PirateKitten: NP--thanks for the second data point!

Comment: Opened Bootstrap ticket: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7061

Comment: After a long gap of seven years (or so it seems), the Google **Engineers** have done it again. Amid Covid-19 they decided to **roll out** their latest gem (ver. 83.0.4103.61) and all hell has broken loose. My app which looked good just the last time I visited it, looks all crappy now thanks to the mandarins at Google. [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48070162?hl=en). NOT only the date widget but input boxes as well have started to look funny. **In case somebody has come across the same problem, may please suggest a remedy**.

Comment: In the end it turned out to be a "design" by choice for the Google team [as they decided to overhaul the "look and feel" of the form controls](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83). But they did not leave the choice to us.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**
Chromium team accepted the bug and submitted a [patch back to WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110974).
The gist of the change is that the date controls will be rendered inside a flexible box element regardless of the style applied to the input[type='date'] control.

---

I'm the one [that reported the defect referenced here to Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=date%20picker&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=178175). One proposed solution is to apply display: inline-block; to the calendar picker:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

However, that is a wonky solution because the controls are still shifted to a location other than right-justified on the input[type="date"] control.

Another option is to float right:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2%;
    float:right;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

This has the side-effect of inverting the spinner and calendar picker controls.

The best hack, I think is to remove the spinner and float right:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2%;
    float:right;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[image: chrome 25 input[type="date"] defect hack-arounds]

Comment: Note that if you're floating an element, its display is set to `block`, so there's no point trying to set it to anything else. See [this CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/), or just take a look at the computed style in Chrome dev tools.

Speaking of those tools, people may not be aware that you can go to Settings>Elements>Show Shadow DOM to see the elements (`-webkit-inner-spin-button` etc) referenced in this answer.

Comment: Chrome version 26.0.1410.43 m displays everything correctly again.

Answer (score 6):

**updated**

**Found Problem**

Bootstrap uses 2 style attributes..

1 - **display:inline-block** which makes google break the arrow onto another line

2 - **height: 20px** which prevents you from seeing this "line"

[image: screenshot of findings]

Comment: I see similar changes when I disable the `padding`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The Google Chrome Issue was marked as a regression, so this will hopefully be fixed soon.
As a temporary workaround, the following will work:

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This way you can keep the inputs display property set to whatever you like and everything works as it did before.

**Original Response**

Setting `display: -webkit-inline-flex` (which seems to be the default for `<input type="date" />`) will fix this issue, this might however alter the layout, as the input is treated like an inline element.

This seems like a bug to me, I'll look if someone already filed a bug report, otherwise I will.

Comment: There is an issue in the chromium bugtracker, feel free to star it to get notified when there is an update and to express your interest in this getting resolved: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=date%20picker&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=178175

Comment: Refer to my previous comment :)

Comment: Thanks @ximi. I also opened a Bootstrap ticket: http://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7061

Comment: @KarlDoyle, removing the property and resetting it aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: @JeromyFrench I'm not sure if the bootstrap guys will fix it, as there isn't really anything wrong with their code, but with chrome's implementation. I just hope the google guys will fix it

Comment: @ximi - true, I see that inline-block doesn't actually remove the arrow put drops it below the input, which you cannot see in bootstrap because the **height:20px**