# Method to show native datepicker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I use `<input type="date">` fields that gracefully fallback to jQuery when the browser does not have support for the field. Relatively recently, Chrome started offering a native date picker, which is great. But I have found that many users miss the little arrow that brings up the calendar and therefore miss the fact that there is an easy calendar for date selection.

[image: Chrome Native Date Picker]

To make this more intuitive, it would be great if I could bring up the native datepicker UI when the user moves the focus to the input or clicks another element (like a small calendar icon).

Is there a method that I can use in Chrome to trigger the datepicker UI?

Comment: if you are asking that I want to get rid of that carrot icon, then I think that is impossible.

Comment: @defau1t you CAN get rid of the arrows with some CSS, but I don't think that's what's being asked. Although to be more consistent, one could probably hide the arrows and fire the native event when the user clicks the calendar.

Comment: I don't know that you can trigger the native date picker to open, but there might be a setting to tell it to open by default?

Comment: @nathan-p, you are welcome ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/e9bat3wh/

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome 99+ added the `showPicker()` method:
https://chromestatus.com/feature/5692248021794816

Full docs and cross-browser compatibility grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker

Example usage:

```html
<input type="date" onfocus="'showPicker' in this && this.showPicker()"/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2023. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker

Comment: Awesome answer, using it in a one-liner results in: `<input type="date" onfocus="'showPicker' in this && this.showPicker()"/>`. 
Or more modern: `<input type="date" onfocus="this.showPicker?.()"/>`

Comment: Thanks, Ken! I've added the first one of those as an example :)

Answer (score 80):

Here is a way to trigger the datepicker when users click on the field itself, because computer illiterate users don't know where they should click:

```css
input[type="date"] {
    position: relative;
}

/* create a new arrow, because we are going to mess up the native one
see "List of symbols" below if you want another, you could also try to add a font-awesome icon.. */
input[type="date"]:after {
    content: "\25BC"; 
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

/* change color of symbol on hover */
input[type="date"]:hover:after {
    color: #bf1400;
}

/* make the native arrow invisible and stretch it over the whole field so you can click anywhere in the input field to trigger the native datepicker*/
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}

/* adjust increase/decrease button */
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    z-index: 1;
}

 /* adjust clear button */
 input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Links:

- [List of symbols](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)
- [codepen example with font-awesome icon](https://codepen.io/andyftp/pen/EQoKxq)

Comment: If you do it like this you lose the functionality of the little up/down buttons.

Comment: @Postlagerkarte That is why i described how to get them working again below the snippet. The snippet is there to give you an idea and you should adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I have adjusted the snippet so it supports the clear, up and down buttons.

Comment: @Andy when we open data-picker dialog clicking on input area, at the same time how can we able to write into input while opening the picker at a time.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda In some browsers you can only type while the native datepicker is closed, so you can click on the left part to not open the datepicker to type or increase the value of `left` in `input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {`, but that takes away the whole purpose of my answer, to cover the field to open the datepicker.

Comment: @Andy Thank you. Can it would be possible as we type in input at the same time date picker is opened and changed according to date and month and year of what we tying in input

Comment: @Postlagerkarte sorry to answer to an old question, but what you mean with "If you do it like this you lose the functionality of the little up/down buttons"?

Comment: @GiacomoM because the css makes the indicator transparent and if you stretch it over the field all the way it covers all the small buttons, making them unclickable.

Comment: @Andy these css rules are for date inputs. Date inputs don't have small buttons on the right. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @GiacomoM it only works in specific browsers ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ as you can see this question and answer is about google chrome which have built in native datepicker. When u want to support other browsers u probably want to use a plugin.

Comment: There seems to have been a breaking change in chrome, causing the icon to no longer be right aligned. Using position absolute fixed it for me, but YMMV: `input[type="date"]:after {...; padding: 0.5rem 1rem; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}`

Answer (score 24):

I don't think you can trigger the native calendar control to display, but you could highlight it a bit more:

```css
input[type="date"]:hover::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  color: red;
}
input[type="date"]:hover:after {
  content: " Date Picker ";
  color: #555;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

You can, as it is, *prevent* it from displaying, e.g, from the docs:

> You can disable the native calendar picker by the following code:

```
<style>
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<input type=date id=dateInput>
<script>
dateInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyIdentifier == "Down") {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Here's the documentation from Webkit, where I got the above:

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls

Maybe that can be torqued and made to display the date picker, but ask yourself if you'd like every calendar control flying out every time you roamed your mouse across a page?

This answer was also helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15107073/451969

Comment: there is way to do it - see my answer

Comment: @MichałŠrajer not anymore

Answer (score 21):

**Edit 2020:** It seems there was a change in chrome, and previous answers do not work anymore.

I made a hacky workaround that you can tune to your needs.

This new method increases size of the calendar icon to overflow it's **input** container in order to completely cover it. You can tune the position and size by tuning these parameters:

```css
  top: -150%;
  left: -150%;
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
```

The bigger, the more stable. But still a hack on top of a hack

---

## Updated July 2020 - Works with new Chrome's calendar-picker

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150%;
  left: -150%;
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:hover + button {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="date">
  <button id="calendar_text">Search Date </button>
</label>
```

There's still an issue in Firefox, when a date is selected and you click near the right border, the input will clear, because the input's clear button is right there.

---

I adapted [cinatic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413985/3163120) so that it works on Chrome, and adapted [Andy's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461709/3163120) to the recent changes of Chrome in 2020

[Andy's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461709/3163120): expands Chrome's datepicker's arrow through out the input

[cinatic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413985/3163120): hides the input on top of another element

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've proposed a corrected version to get rid of the firefox issue.

Comment: You should set tabindex="-1" on the input element to avoid it getting the focus when someone uses keyboard navigation (TAB key)

Answer (score 18):

Referencing [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome#answer-45461709), I made whole area clickable and just removed the calendar icon.

The result in Andy's snippet has small area on the left that is not clickable. (Chrome 87.0.4280.66)

```css
input.picker[type="date"] {
  position: relative;
}

input.picker[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input class="picker" type="date">
```

Answer (score 15):

The trick is to fire <kbd>F4</kbd> KeyboardEvent on input element:

```
function openPicker(inputDateElem) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    ev.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, document.defaultView, 'F4', 0);
    inputDateElem.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

var cal = document.querySelector('#cal');
cal.focus();
openPicker(cal);
```

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2d0vzrr/

BTW, there is an interesting bug in chrome. If you open jsfiddle in separate tab, the calendar popup will be shown on current tab.
It's already [reported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501357).

Comment: initKeyboardEvent is deprecated, is there any alternative to above script with out using the `initKeyboardEvent`.

Comment: at least in chrome you should use 
inputDateElem.focus();
before dispatching

Comment: This does not work, at least not anymore. MDN states - `Note: manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Answer (score 5):

For desktop (and mobile), place input in a div with relative positioning and an icon, with the input styled as follows:

```
input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;

  &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This stretches the picker indicator over the complete parent div, so that it always shows the date control when you tap the parent div's icon and/or text.

Answer (score 5):

2021 Firefox / Chrome update of [Madacol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483852/646056) reply.

Inspired by other replies I pushed a little further [Madacol's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483852/646056) to get rid of the bad behaviour under firefox when you clicked on the right of the button (reseting the input). Here it is.

```css
.datepicker{
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: clip;
}
.datepicker:focus-within {
    outline: black auto 2px;
}
.datepicker > input[type=date] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.datepicker > input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150%;
  left: -150%;
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tested on 2021-09 under latest chrome and firefox -->
<label class="datepicker">
  
  <input type="date" value="2021-09-30" />  
</label>
```

Comment: Update as of may 2023 this solution doesn't work anymore with latest firefox version

Answer (score 2):

I think people want very often to use another icon or element to open the native datepicker box.

I figured out that the javascript solution with "click() & .focus()" only **works** in webkit and some other desktop browsers but **unfortunatly not in FireFox**.

But It is possible by another way, by overlaying the inputField over the icon element (or whatever you want to use) and made it invinsible by opacity 0.

This **works really great** on **mobile devices**, for desktop devices i would suggest you to add the onclick event as fallback "$('.dateInpuBox').click().focus()"

```css
    .myBeautifulIcon {
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .dateInputBox {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="myBeautifulIcon">
  ICON
  <input class="dateInputBox" type="date" />
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work as intended in Chrome 93 on Linux (not sure about Windows). Picker icon is smaller than whole input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another label that natively trigger browser datepicker. Tested on Firefox:

```
<input type="date" id="started[date]" name="started[date]">
<label class="btn btn-info btn-date" type="button" for="started[time]">
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Probably the best answer, since it's not relying on hacks, but native behavior of html elements. One should be able to achieve the desired look via css and use this to make sure it works anywhere.

Comment: doesn't really work, at least not in Chrome - a label, when triggered, just _focuses_ the target element, won't exactly open its controls.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add my answer for anyone looking for an even simpler, quicker solution. I just use two events in the input `.onfocus` and `.onblur`

```
<input type="text" name="date_picked" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```

Works in all browsers as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The onfocus causes the input to appear like a date picker and when its clicked off, it shows the date. Just wanted to add clarification