# how to open calender for a date field in HTML5 mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app using HTML5 and jQuery mobile.
I have a form containing a field of the type "date":

```
<form id="registrationForm">
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth"/>
   </div>
   <img id="calendar_logo"/>
</form>
```

When the user taps the field, the browser native calender shows.
What i need, is for that calender to show upon a click on the calender_logo image.

I tried setting the focusin with jQuery, but it does'nt work:

```
$('#calendar_logo').click(function(){
        $("#registrationForm input[name='dateOfBirth']").focusin();
});
```

Can anybody please help?

thank you!

Comment: check this link http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use jQuery's plugin for this. I want the native browser's date picker to show.

Comment: sorry but I don't get it, you use jquery mobile, you post jquery function, so if you want create cross browser calendar you will be need jquery or other framework. Maybe this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome

Comment: have you tried `click` instead of `focusin`?

Comment: is this what you mean? Try the down arrow in the date box: http://jsfiddle.net/wuZ7R/

Comment: mcmac - sorry, maybe i should have explained myself a little better. I DON'T want a cross broswer calender. I want the integral "date picker" window to pop up when you press the calender_logo

Comment: loco - you know how you click the little black arrow, and the calender pops up? i want the same thing happen when i click my calender logo image.

Comment: sv_in - is "click" also an action? not just an event?
either way, it doe'nt work...

Answer (score 2):

Your calendar logo could be wrapped in a label tag that points to the field. You just need to give the field an ID.

```
<form id="registrationForm">
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"/>
   </div>
    <label for="dateOfBirth">
        <img id="calendar_logo"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

Most browsers will focus the field if the user clicks on the label.

Comment: This does not open the calendar in Chrome.