# Using jQuery Mobile Date picker with a trigger button

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm using standard JQM date picker with input tag like this

```
<input type="date" data-clear-btn="false" id="dp" value="2006-09-14">
```

on request here is jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GardenOfEmuna/47VUw/

Now I want to display value in a trigger button and open datepicker upon clicking on it.

Has anyone idea how to open datepicker with a trigger button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a jqm datepicker, since there is none. You are using the native browser datepicker control and you can't trigger it as proved in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome)

Possible solution:

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tronc/xra77/), it uses the `datepicker` from jquery ui with a wrapper class as shown in the jqm documentation ([link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/))

#### html

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="content">
           <input id='myDatePicker' type="text" data-role="date">
           <button id='myButton' class="ui-btn">Button</button>   
    </div>
</div>
```

#### js

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        $('#myDatePicker').datepicker( "show" );
    });
});
```

#### resources

- jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
- jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work on jqm and link pointing to jqui stuff :(

Comment: i added jsfiddle link to question