# How to invoke date picker from date input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, html-input

Chrome has native date picker for `<input type="date">`:
[image: date picker for date input in chrome]

I like it, and it's totally ok with me to have it work only in chrome.

The question is **how can I invoke date picker for this input field in javascript?**

Normally there is only input field until user focus it and click little black triangle to open small calendar. I want to open it from javascript.

I would like to avoid 3rd party date picker implementations if possible.

I've tried `element.focus()`, `element.click()`, etc.

Comment: My guess would be that you can't. It's not visible markup, can't add an event to it, and just clicking the `input` doesn't cause it. And you can't move the mouse pointer with JS, no API for it, not that I know of.

Comment: When is it useful to be able to do this? What is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The trick is to send F4 keyboard event.

See details in my answer for (indeed) duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome/30895180#30895180)

Comment: Coo, that works in Chrome. But it seem this is not the standard war that works everywhere?

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work on mine. Tried triggering keyCode 115(F4) to an element but nothing happens.

Comment: Won't work ... check MDN (or comments on the linked answer)