# HTML5 button to trigger date input on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML5 design where I want to be able to use a button to display a date, but I want to use the HTML5 input type="date" to select the date.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> <span class="date">27 Jul 2015</span>
</button>
<input type="date" class="hidden" id="tbDate" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnDate").click(function () {
            $("#tbDate").focus();
        });
    });             
</script>
```

I've tried focus() and click() - neither work...any ideas?

Comment: Why the input is hidden ? Do you want to click on button and then show in input the button date ?

Comment: @Zl3n I don't want the input displayed at all - only the button, but I want the button to trigger the mobile's native date picker.

Comment: @series0ne Which mobile OS/browser are you using?

Comment: @Vucko - iOS, but it needs to work on Android and Windows Mobile too ideally

Comment: @series0ne well, `type=date` has a [bed support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)), especially for mobile browsers. I'd recommend that you try with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30895180/1763929).

Comment: `.click()` works on Chrome/Android but not on Firefox/Android as long as the input is hidden by `visibility:hidden`. It doesn't work if it's hidden by `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set `val()` for `input`. Hope this help

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> <span class="date">27 Jul 2015</span>
</button>
<input type="date" class="hidden" id="tbDate" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnDate").click(function () {
          var date = new Date("2015, 07, 27");
          var setDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-"+("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            $("#tbDate").val(setDate);
        });
    });             
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this the answer? This does not trigger the `<input='date' />` in order to select a date as asked in the question.

Comment: he want a button to input date. I understand like that.

Comment: He wants a button to *display* the date but he said "I want to use the HTML5 input type="date" to select the date."

Answer (score 3):

Please browse with your phone.

```html
<label for="dateInput">click button</label>
<input type="date" id="dateInput" />
```

Comment: Err, there is no button in your example. There's only a label and a text box. Perhaps you missed a step somewhere?

Comment: Label tag instead of button.(From google translation)

Comment: There's no option to run code snippet when I opened it from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `showPicker()` api:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const dateComponent = document.getElementById("date");

btn.addEventListner("click", () => {
    dateComponent.showPicker();
})
```