# How can I show calendar but not input box of input type=date?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a default value set in my `<input type=date>` and I would like to display only the calendar and not the input box.

I am trying to do it with `Javascript` but without success as I show below:

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

date.click();
```

```css
input[type="date"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" value="2016-06-02" readonly>
```

As you can see, nothing is displayed (it does not seem that `click` event could be apply to that input because it does not matter if I have it displayed or not, click event does not work).

I would like to show only the calendar(not the input) and make it read-only (already done) on the screen all the time that the webpage will be displayed.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:** For a better clarification, when I refer to calendar I mean to the calendar that is shown when you click on the `input type=date`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a separate "calendar widget" or when you say you want to show only the calendar are you talking about the text "2016-06-02"?

Comment: @JonSG When I talk about calendar I mean the calendar that appears when you click on the dropdown of the `input type=date`.

Comment: @Error404 input[type="date"]{
  display: none;
} isn't doing much. You want the "calendar" to disappear when you click it ?

Comment: @Pleasure No. I want to always hide the input box but show the calendar instead (as when you click on the input box and it is shown, but without the input box).

Comment: @Error404 Oh you mean on chrome ? Because on firefox nothing happens. I know that the type "date" is only in certain browsers.

Comment: @Pleasure Yes, I mean in Chrome. In Chrome when you click on it, a calendar is displayed and you can go through it.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to display onload the native calendar, here is a solution :

1 - As you can't hide the input AND show the calendar, set its opacity to 0 :

```
input[type="date"]{
  opacity:0;
}
```

2 - As Michał Šrajer showed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome) you can trigger the event via firing F4 key event :

```
function openPicker(inputDateElem) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    ev.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, document.defaultView, 'F4', 0);
    inputDateElem.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

var cal = document.querySelector('#cal');
cal.focus();
openPicker(cal);
```

This will hide the input and show the calendar.

*Remember that this will not work in Firefox*

Comment: Thank you! Very very close of the behaviour intended. Do you know if I can fix the calendar to be always displayed? Without block the webpage, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use JQuery UI which is a plugin to create user-friendly UI elements.

Check this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline).

In the example you can see the code that it is used. It is very easy, you only need to invoke the datepicker, and it is done by these lines:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: It is what I am trying to avoid. Use plugins or whatever external stuff. It is going to be my last option to choose if I did not get one that works for the `input type=date`.

Comment: okei, just take in count that using this plugin works in almost every common browser. If you chose the pure HTML5 way, you will be very limited. Check the compatibility http://caniuse.com/#search=date