# How could i reach click event to get date calender in input type="date" when click button

Tags: reactjs, date, input, onclick, mouseclick-event

[image]
i cant get render the calender box while clicking button.

Comment: Coudn't you explain what do you mean in different words?

Comment: what i want is when i click the click me button i need to get the calendar box  to choose data , not to focus the dd/mm/yyyy box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37596360/5089567 Maybe this answer will help, but it's kind of hacking. What is usually done on website is creating a custom calendar input.

Comment: ok @KonradLinkowski i ll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [date , setdate] = useState();

<input type="date" onChange={(e)=>{setdate(e.target.value);alert(date)} }  />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).