# How to open a hidden InputDate from code in blazor

Tags: forms, blazor

I want to do a custom page where you can pick a date, but the squared box with the selected date is not visible. I want a button that you click, then, it opens the date picker, you select the date, and it gets visualized in my custom component.

My first idea was to have a <InputDate @ref=dateinput/> in my code, with `display:none;` or something like this. Then when clicking on my button, use the dateinput reference to make it open the selector. But I cannot find a way to do that.

A simplified version of the code would look like this:

```
<div>
  <button @onclick=OpenPicker>Click here</button>
  <EditForm Model="@model">
     <InputDate @ref=inputDate class="HiddenInputDate" @bind-Value=@Mode.Date />
  </EditForm>
  <div>@mode.SelectedDate.ToString()</div>
</div>

@code{
  InputDate<DateTime> inputDate = new();

  void OpenPicker() {
     inputDate.OpenDatePickerDialog(); //How to do this???
  }
}
```

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a bool to show and hide your datepicker. Something like this:

```
@page "/"
    
    <button @onclick="ShowDatePicker">Open Date Picker</button>
    
    <div>
        Selected Date: @SelectedDate
    </div>
    
    @if (showDatePicker)
    {
        <input type="date" @bind="SelectedDate"  />
    }
    
    @code {
        private bool showDatePicker;
        private DateTime? SelectedDate { get; set; }
    
        private void ShowDatePicker()
        {
            showDatePicker = !showDatePicker;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just saw that you updated your question with new code. Let me know i my sample is still useful.

Comment: the key point is that I want to show the "floating box" with the dates to select, but NOT the input field with the digits showing the selected date

Comment: is that your question ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595925/how-can-i-show-calendar-but-not-input-box-of-input-type-date

Comment: nop, that's not me. And I'm trying to stay away from JS

Comment: @javirs yes i know it is not you, but it is more or less the same question. You are trying to display the calendar without the inputbox. of an input element. The rendered html element is the same for `<input type="date"/>` and `<InputDate/>`  However if you do not wont to call the JSRuntime... I don't think it is possible without js.