# How to manually trigger a click event on a dom in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to manually trigger a onclick event on a input element. I did some search and wrote the code as below.

```
<input type="date" ref={datePicker => this.datePicker = datePicker}/>
            <button
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      this.datePicker.click()
                    }}>
             Select the data
            </button>
```

Then I also tried below code:

```
<input type="date" ref='datePicker'/>
                <button
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          this.refs.datePicker.click()
                        }}>
                 Select the data
                </button>
```

None of above code works. When I click the button , nothing happens. I expect to open the data picker ui.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @Ro If reactjs supports this I don't want to bring another dependency into my application

Comment: @CodeBling The datePicker is defined in the <input> tag. I want to show the date picker triggered by the input tag.

Comment: @CodeBling It is already there. Look at the first line of my code. The <input> tag has a property ref which point to datePicker.

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both your examples, and the `<input>` element's `.click()` method is indeed called. The reason it's not working as you expect is that it the click only puts the keyboard focus in the element, it does not click the date picker. Opening the date picker programmatically is [currently not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome#comment68718752_30895180), at least not in all browsers.

Comment: Is there any way for me to customize the <input type='date'> ui?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15531938/675721. I think you can make minor adjustments, but not really. See also https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome#how_do_i_change_the_appearance_of_the_date_picker

Answer (score 0):

Try without calling it as a function:

`onClick={(e) => {this.datePicker.click}}>`