# show timepicker on click whole input type time HTML5 field not only on little clock icon

Tags: html, input

show time-picker on click whole input type time HTML5 field not only on the little clock icon

For now, it is only triggered while clicking on a small clock icon inside the field, I want it to be trigger on the whole field click.

Comment: Which time picker component are you using? In most cases you can manually trigger showing a timepicker by calling something like `$('input#from').on('click', function() { $("#date").datepicker("show"); });` (assuming that the datepicker is bound to `<input id="date">`).

Comment: I'm using normal HTML5 input type time

Comment: Hi @ArunMaurya Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML time input type - how to let select time menu view when click anywhere not only clock icon click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058103/html-time-input-type-how-to-let-select-time-menu-view-when-click-anywhere-not)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding this line to css..

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the showPicker function in the onfocus event

```
<input type="time" onfocus="this.showPicker()">
```

Credit to : [How to show calendar popup when input[type="date"] is on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334960/how-to-show-calendar-popup-when-inputtype-date-is-on-focus/72627382#72627382)

Answer (score 0):

I have added these lines to my .css

```
input[type=time] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```