# HTML time input type - how to let select time menu view when clicking anywhere not only clock icon click

Tags: html, input, time

I working on the **time input** type in HTML, my problem is when I click on the small **clock icon** on the right side of the input, the selectable time menu is viewed but I need to show it when I click anywhere on input.
[image]

I found this question but this does not solve my problem because it's about Timepacker, not HTML only.

[show timepicker on click whole input type time HTML5 field not only on little clock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810068/show-timepicker-on-click-whole-input-type-time-html5-field-not-only-on-little-cl)

HTML :

```
  <label for="first" class="">{{__('From Hour')}}</label>
   <input type="time" class="form-control input-md"name="" id="from_hour" value="">
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @JSN not yet i still waiting .

Comment: I guess, I will use jquery datetime picker then. haha

Answer (score 7):

For me, adding `onfocus="this.showPicker()"` attribute on the time input solved the problem.

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72627382/10414071

Answer (score 3):

This style works fine in my case:

```
input[type="time"] {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @StepPen-codes at [How To Open HTML Date Picker Dialog On Click Anywhere Inside Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270341/how-to-open-html-date-picker-dialog-on-click-anywhere-inside-input)

You can use CSS to do the trick. It works but in my case, the calendar icon disappears. I try to bring it back but the position isn't nice.

```
input#session-date::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #0000;
  position:absolute;
  transform: scale(12)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inputfield{
          position: relative;
          width: 100px;
      }
      input {
        border: 1px solid #bfc9e2;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        background: transparent;
        width: 100px;
      }
      input[type=time]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
          bottom: 0;
          color: transparent;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: auto;
          left: 0;
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%
      }
      .clock-img {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0px;
          top: 10px;
          z-index: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Sample Test</h1>

<form>
    
  <div class="inputfield">
    <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt">
    <span class="clock-img"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).