# How do I show the HTML input date when clicking text or an image?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to pop up a date picker when I click some text or an image.
I am using reactjs. I'm using the HTML `input type="date"` not the React-datepicker library.

Here is my code:

```js
    import { useRef } from "react";
    const add = () => {
      const interviewDateRef = useRef();
      const handleInterviewDateClick = () => {
        interviewDateRef.current.focus();
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleInterviewDateClick}>Change Date</button>
          <input type="date" ref={interviewDateRef} className="hidden" />
        </>
      );
    };
    export default add;
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-popup-qtr9o?file=/src/Add.jsx).

I want the date picker to work normally, but also to appear when clicking on text or an image. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: i'm not using react datepicker. just html input date basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage to do this by opening the dropdown on focus. Since clicking the button focus the input.

Here is how to do so

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useRef} = React;

const Add = () => {
  const interviewDateRef = useRef();
  const handleInterviewDateClick = () => {
    interviewDateRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleInterviewDateClick}>Change Date</button>
      <input type="date" ref={interviewDateRef} className="hidden" />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Add />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.input-container input {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    padding: .75rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334960/how-to-show-calendar-popup-when-inputtype-date-is-on-focus/51349612#51349612) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need of react JS if you are using input type date then there automatically when you click on it, it pop up is the date a picker window you can edit it with CSS

Answer (score 1):

The label element may do exactly what you are looking for without any extra javascript. As long as the `label`'s `for` (`htmlFor` in React) is linked to the input's id or the input is nested in the `label` it should open the calendar. There may be some cross-browser differences here though.

```
<>
  <label htmlFor="input-id">Change Date</button>
  <input id="input-id" type="date" />
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me, the one which worked is this one:

```
interviewDateRef.current.showPicker();
```

you just have to call `showPicker()` function instead of `focus()`