# Trigger Chrome and Edge native datepicker by clicking anywhere in input

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Date picker that can only be clicked on icon]

Clicking on the circled icon brings up the date picker for Chrome and Edge, but my computer illiterate test users don't know where to click and complain it doesn't work.

Is there a way to make the date picker show up when clicking anywhere on the input box?

I have tried the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome), but it doesn't work. I am using the latest Chrome/Edge Browser and Bootstrap 4.6.

Here is the HTML for my input field:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
   <label class="control-label" for="Date">Date:</label>
   <input id="Date" type="date" class="form-control picker" name="Date" value="" />
</div>
```

Many thanks to Firefox for doing this by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show calendar popup when input\[type="date"\] is on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334960/how-to-show-calendar-popup-when-inputtype-date-is-on-focus)

Comment: It's a css hack similar to the answer I ended up with, and it's not cross browser.  He specifically mentioned supporting Edge.  I'm sure the hack could be extended, but I think he'd be better off with a different datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the whole input element to show the date picker using event listener like so:

```
const dateInput = document.getElementById('dateInput');

dateInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dateInput.click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not trigger the calender from js (my original thought), so I made a (hacky) solution where I use css to resize the calendar target area and then place it over the entire input area.  scaleX(-1) is to flip it so the calendar icon stays on the left.  I put a red border around the calendar area so you can see it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #Date::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50;
        transform:scaleX(-1);
        top: 10px;
        width: 95px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid red;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="Date">Date:</label>
      <input id="Date" type="date" class="form-control picker" name="Date" value="" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the datepicker invocation for Chrome/Edge? I just have the date input field.

Comment: Hold on.  I'm reading the documentation.  I was under the impression that the invocation was exposed, but it may not be.  I figured that out when I tried to edit the answer to just trigger the picker.  Give me about 15 minutes and if I haven't got it I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Ok, I could not trigger the event from code.  Here is a solution where I use css to resize the calender target area and place it over the box.  I put a red border around it so you can see it.    It's kind of hacky.  For one thing, you can't enter a date manually.  Sorry.  I will keep looking at this.

Comment: That definitely works for Chrome. Unfortunately, it does nothing on Edge. For now, I have a hacky popup giving Edge users explicit instructions to click the icon.

Comment: It is definitely not optimal.  All of the solutions (I've seen about 20+) rely on css hacks.  You can probably make it support Edge/Firefox/etc if you try, but I will see what I can figure out on a non-css option.  Problem is the implementation is browser specific and exposes very few methods.

Comment: you could implement a different datepicker (jquery datetimepicker for instance) and could invoke that through code, but it sucks to have to load a library just for this.

Comment: I guess I'll go looking for 3rd party datepickers, then.