# Masked Input - Date Picker

Tags: javascript, input-mask, imaskjs

I want to develop an date picker with using the [InputMask.js library](https://imask.js.org/) and blazor. We've been using it for various input field in our application, so setting the library up isn't really the problem.

In our design, we've specified that in input field should use the native browser date-picker from the `<input type="date"/>` [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rKYQ.png).

Now to the question: How does one impement a native-date picker with iMask.js? I've been searching for quite a while and I haven't any examples. Whenever I try to add a mask-id to the input and bind it as such:

##### HTML

```html
<input type="date" id='date-mask'/>
```

##### JS

```js
let mask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('date-mask'),
  {
    mask: Date,
    min: new Date(1990, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
    lazy: false
  }
);
```

after clicking on the date-picker, the date does not apply and it throws a warning saying:

`Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask using mask.updateValue() to work properly.`

Trying to bind the `onchange` event doesn't even work and the event is not fired. Maybe it's because im taking over someone elses code (*who shall remain nameless*) or maybe it's just me - but I can't seem to figure it out.

#### TLDR

How does one implement a native date-picker with the validation of imask.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually possible. _Setting_ the value of date input fields always needs to happen in `yyyy-mm-dd` format; and how it actually _displays_, is dependent on the user's locale settings.

Comment: I guess you could hide the actual `date` input field, [trigger the picker via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73484603/1427878), and then write the selected date into a normal text field, and apply your mask on the latter. But that probably won't work well, if the user then wants to "type" date parts ...