# how can i get date-picker on clicking dd ,mm or yyyy of the html input type=date

Tags: javascript, html, angular

my question is about :how can I get date-picker on clicking `dd ,mm or yyyy` of the html `input type=date`

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: It's default nature, what's issue in that?

Comment: I have an input date field like-<input type="date">  which produces an input field in the format dd-mm-yyyy .The date picker gets opened only on clicking the caret icon at the far right.I want the datepicker to open on clicking not only caret icon but also the input fields dd,mm or yyyy

Comment: This answer is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461709/7785555

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method to show native datepicker in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome)

Comment: But i also want to edit the date using keyboard ..in addition to triggering the datepicker