# Hide the calendar icon in Google Chrome

Tags: css, date, google-chrome, input

Does anyone know how to hide the calendar icon on a date field in Chrome?

```html
<input type="date" />
```

When I look it up I find that I should use `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Don't be put off by the question title I've linked to_ as well as the reference to `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` there are some comments on this SO question that might prove useful _  >>>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome

Answer (score 53):

Try something like this

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="date-input">
```

Comment: You can also add to it setting the opacity to ```opacity: 0```. That way, the icon will be hidden in chrome based browsers while still retaining the functionality to show the date picker when users click on the location where the icon is ought to be.

Comment: i removed it but instead of that i want use my own icon, but how do i trigger date picker now..

Comment: @PawanDeore you should try `showPicker()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker

Comment: There are several issues with this: 1) it doesn't hide the date icon in Firefox, 2) it leaves a bit of extra white space to the right of the input in Chrome, 3) you don't need to select `input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button`, 4) You only need the `display: none`, not anything affecting `appearance`.

Comment: Doesnt work anymore. (Firefox)

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro added solution for firefox below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77401705/2440049

Answer (score 2):

Use below CSS to hide the calender sign from the calender icon from input.

```
input[type='date']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='date']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {background: 
transparent;
bottom: 0;
color: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
height: auto;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Method to hide the native datepicker icon which works in Chrome and Firefox.

**Chrome**

The native ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator is used

**Non webkit Browser like Firefox**

I simply added an after element on the wrapper as an overlay to hide the native icon. This overlay is not used on chrome.

```css
.date-input-wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.date-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.date-input-wrapper::after {
  display: none;
  width: 17px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  /* background: white; */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 0px;
  top: 2px;
}

@supports not selector(::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator) {
  .date-input-wrapper::before {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="date-input-wrapper">
  <input type="date">
</div>
```