# MUI grid squishing together items in chrome despite explicit setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am creating a modal with MUI. Currently, everything works fine except for the fact that on chrome, the textfield items inside of a grid container are being squished together. The weird thing is I don't have this problem on safari or on the CodeSandbox online editor. Also, the problem only occurs in the md and lg window sizes. I have pasted screenshots and my code below. I removed some things from the code (button functionality and such) so that it is easier to look at and just focus on styling.

```
return (
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogTitle>Edit Dates</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
              <DialogContentText>
                Please enter the new dates for Cover Crop Planting, Biomass Harvest, Cover Crop
                Termination, and Cash Planting in the text fields below. If you need to change a bag
                pickup timing, leave a comment.
              </DialogContentText>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
              <TextField
                color="primary"
                type="date"
                id="Cover Crop Planting"
                label="Cover Crop Planting"
                variant="outlined"
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
              <TextField
                color="primary"
                type="date"
                id="Biomass Harvest"
                label="Biomass Harvest"
                variant="outlined"
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
              <TextField
                color="primary"
                type="date"
                id="Cover Crop Termination"
                label="Cover Crop Temination"
                variant="outlined"
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
              <TextField
                color="primary"
                type="date"
                id="Cash Planting"
                label="Cash Planting"
                variant="outlined"
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={6} lg={6}>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                fullWidth={true}
              >
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={6} lg={6}>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                fullWidth={true}
              >
                Update
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
```

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feDiZ.png)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc0jN.png)

Comment: when you add `type="date"` default date picker of chrome is appearing. you may want to hide it. please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892727/hide-the-calendar-icon-in-google-chrome