# How to make a HTML calendar always visible to the user

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am using the HTML calendar and I am asking whether i can make this visible to the user at all times. Right now, the user clicks on the search date for the calendar to appear. I am wondering if there is a way with JavaScript or jQuery to make this always visible. This is what I want always to be visible. Also, I don't want to use the jQuery calendar if possible.

[image]

```
<input id="datepicker"  type="date" name="Date: " value="" min="2016-01-01" max="">
<input id="submitbutton" type="button" onclick="Submit()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method to show native datepicker in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome)

Comment: I dont think so, What i have in the picture above is what I want the user to see when  the website is loaded. I want the calendar to be visible at all times. I dont want the user to click on the search bar to get to the calendar. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes, and the answers to that question note that there is no way of having the datepicker show without user interaction.