# Open html5 datepicker on input click

Tags: html, css, input, datepicker

By default, the datepicker opens when the icon is clicked.

Now, i want the datepicker to appear when the input field is clicked.
I can achieve this by enlarging the icon to 100% width, but i can't make it transparent, so there would be no icon at all but only the text visible...

I think i have seen solutions fro this the other day, but now, i did not find anything at all.

How can i get the desired effect?
PS: A onFocus solution would be even better than onClick.

```css
input#modified::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
Normal: only icon-click shows datepicker 
<input type="datetime-local" ><br>
Modified: click red outline for datepicker
<input type="datetime-local" id="modified">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method to show native datepicker in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome)

Comment: Yes, it is the Page I had seen before. The answer I used is linked in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome/65138737#65138737) works for me.
It is the answer that i had seen before but did not find.