# Styling input[type=date] in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, datepicker

I'm using html5 date input, but in a new form Chrome is not displaying the full values correctly. The format is DD-MM-YYYY, but the YYYY part shows up blank. I can see the value is there though.

Seems as if the white space on the right side of the input is reserved for the controls (cross to clear value, up/down arrow, dropdown-arrow).

I don't have space to make the input wider. How to make the full date visible?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/U6MYy/

```
<input type="date" value="2014-04-07"/>
with
input { width: 80px; }
```

Comment: It's the default behaviour for a input type="date" box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a chrome bug which you can read about here:

[Chrome Input Date Bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108069)

apparently fixed, but can't managed to make it work their patch here:

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/141195

your quick solution right now is set `width` to minimum `130px`

UPDATE: see this answer, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15107073/3448527

Comment: Thanks, doesn't solve it but at least I've got something to tell my users :)

Comment: Sorry can't help you more than this. But here to help anytime :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have come up with a nice solution. The only fault I've found thus far is that if you decide to keep any of the tools & shrink the input the tools will overlap the value.

Here is the solution I am partial to:

```
input[type='date']{position:relative;}
::-webkit-datetime-edit, ::-webkit-clear-button, ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{position:absolute;}
::-webkit-clear-button{right:1.54em;}
::-webkit-inner-spin-button{-webkit-appearance:none; margin:0;}
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{right:0; padding:.539em .34em;}
```

This keeps the clear button (x) & the dropdown arrow but removes those pesky arrows.

This should get you at least part way to where you want to be. You can open you Dev Tools in Chrome & Settings > Elements > Show user agent shadow DOM. From here you can play with the styles to find exactly what you want.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070600/why-has-the-behavior-of-input-type-date-changed/15107073#15107073) the following code Crashes Chrome on hover (so be warned):

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-clear-button,
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
```

Users can't use the built-in calendar popup.