# How to remove arrows on hover of<input type=date> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, datepicker, font-awesome

I've created date picker as a button,and when hovering it, it looks messy in chrome browser. may be the reason is only because of its default behavior in browsers but can I change that hover effect on chrome?

***Image in Firefox:***

**Default `<input type=date>`**

[image]

**Button `<input type=date>`**

[image]

***Image in Chrome:***

**Default `<input type=date>` (when hover)**

[image]

**Button `<input type=date>` (when hover)**

[image]

Is there any way to remove that hover effect on Chrome?

```css
.date-picker-button {
  background: #8DBF42;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8DBF42;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  width: 300px;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #cdd7e1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block !important;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
}

.date-picker-button .date-picker-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #8DBF42;
  border: none;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 55px;
}

.fa.fa-angle-down {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  top: 0px !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.fa-calendar-o {
  color: white !important;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="date-picker-button input-group">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Select Date</span>
  <input class="input-startdate date-picker-input hasDatepicker" name="effdate" id="dp1523936970319" aria-required="true" required="" type="date">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909969/styling-inputtype-date-in-chrome

Comment: Can you add your css styles?

Comment: @benams I've posted the css please have a look

Comment: Boostrap offers customisation for date pickers. You can find the documentation with the following link: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. I've used this in a few of my web applications and it works across IE, Edge and Chrome.

Comment: Changing how clicking works is behaviour, not appearance. Unfortunately, it's very unlikely that you'll have cross browser way of changing behaviour on standard `<input type="date" />`. So it's better to tweak some 3rd party implementation like bootstrap, jQuery UI etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it will hide everything:

```css
input#myInput::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none }

input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: The arrows will hide, but date picker does not show in chrome.

Comment: Because date picker will show only after clicking on that down arrow.

Comment: If you need the arrow, just ignore the first line.

Comment: I don't need arrow..can It be possible to show date picker on clicking anywhere in button in chrome browser?

Comment: Thank you so much, I've changed my element and have given required css and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is working to hide the input buttons:

```css
::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date"  id="myInput">
```

Comment: The arrows will hide, but date picker does not show in chrome.

Comment: Because date picker will show only after clicking on that down arrow.

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela It would be much easier to fix if you provide CSS to reproduce this issue.

Comment: please take a look there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I've edited the question with css, please check it on chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this answer: [Method to show native datepicker in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530850/method-to-show-native-datepicker-in-chrome/30895180#answer-45461709) which shows how you can stretch the arrow across the entire input, which then allows clicking anywhere within the input field to trigger the date picker.

Comment: It is working nice..but I've changed my element already.thank you..:).